# Relation between two critical regions when the level of the test is changed

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study

Based on a random sample of size n,denote the $\alpha$-level critical region for a hypothesis testing problem $H_0$ vs. $H_1$ as $C_{\alpha}$,if we change the level to $\alpha_1<\alpha$,then can it be said that $C_{\alpha_1}\subseteq C_{\alpha}$ or
$C_{\alpha}\subseteq C_{\alpha_1}?$which one will be true?

As we know that if the rejection of null hypothesis is not so serious,one can take a high value as the level of a test.now if we take the level of a test a small value i.e.,the probability of rejecting the true null hypothesis is considered as a serious error,does that imply that the new critical region will be a subset of the previous?

Comment: It is an immediate consequence of the axioms of probability that one of those inclusions, if interpreted as *proper* subsets, must be incorrect.  (I leave it to you to determine which one that is.)  Whether the other one is necessarily true might depend on the methods and principles you use to develop those critical regions.